# Can't move character forward/backward using 'MovePosition'

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I can't get my character to move backward or forwards- but left and right work perfectly fine! The inputs in the project are fine, there's nothing crazy I did with the physics on the rigidbody, I just can't seem to figure out the issue.

**Portion of code pertaining to movement:**

```
 if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) {
        gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(gameObject.transform.position + (gameObject.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 10 * hSpeedMult * Time.deltaTime));
        posAt = gameObject.transform.position;
    }
    else {
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(posAt.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, posAt.z);
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0) {
        gameObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(gameObject.transform.position + (gameObject.transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * 10 * vSpeedMult * Time.deltaTime));
        posAt = gameObject.transform.position;
    }
    else {
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(posAt.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, posAt.z);
    }
```

The "posAt" is just used to make sure the player cannot move when no controls are pressed.

[image: visual studio code screenshot]
[image: moving error]

Answer (score 0):

Once I removed the "position freezer", it did the trick. My "PosAt" lines were the problem.

[image]